# How do I find $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{x}^{\infty} f(t, x) \mathrm{d} t$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, chain-rule, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to compute the following derivative:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\Big(\int_{x}^{\infty} f(t, x) \mathrm{d} t\Big)}{\mathrm{d}x} \text{.}\tag{1}$$

It is straightforward to compute the following derivative using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\Big(\int_{x}^{\infty} f(t) \mathrm{d} t\Big)}{\mathrm{d}x}  = - f(x)\text{,}\tag{2}$$

but I am not sure how to change this if $x$ appears in the integrand.

I attempted to use wolframalpha.com, and received the following [output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20%28integral%20of%20f%28t%2C%20x%29%20from%20t%20%3D%20x%20to%20t%3D%20infinity%29%20with%20respect%20to%20x):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\Big(\int_{t=x}^{\infty} f(t, x) \mathrm{d} t\Big)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \int_{x}^{\infty} f^{(0, 1)}(t, x) \mathrm{d} t - f(x, x)\text{,}\tag{3}$$

but I do not know the meaning of $f^{(0, 1)}(t, x)$ or where this solution comes from.

**Edit**: You can assume $f$ satisfies reasonable smoothness properties.

Comment: If your "variable of integration" is $t$, you can't differentiate the integral with respect to it. Almost surely you mean to differentiate with respect to $x$ (and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus...). Even if the issue was presented to you exactly as such, I'd wager that it was a typo.

Comment: @paulgarrett yes, that was a repeated typo. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{(0,1)}$ in WolphramAlpha means the partial derivative over the second argument, that is
$$ f^{(0,1)}(t,x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x)$$
The result that was given to you comes from the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).